# How to echo a request in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

How do I make apache echo the original request in the response body? Is CGI needed?

**UPDATE:**

Nevermind, I wrote a simple web server in Perl :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php then you can use a snippet like this somewhere in your page

```
foreach($_SERVER as $k=>$v)  {
    print $k.': '.$v."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I needed the request exactly as it was sent, and I'm not sure foreach on hashtable works that way :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd most likely have to use some kind of scripting language like PHP to accept the request and echo out the headers and content of the request.